# pgettext in jinja2 django templates

Tags: python, django, jinja2, gettext

I have configured the Jinja environment with `env.install_gettext_translations(translation, newstyle=True)` and the `jinja2.ext.i18n` extension.
I can only use the `_()`, `_gettext()` and `ngettext()` functions in my jinja2 templates.

I want to use `pgettext()` ([django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/translation/#contextual-markers)) as well to add a context to the translatable strings. Is there an extension that does this, or am I missing something?

**update**: I have posted a feature request [#793](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues/793). I would still like to know whether there is an answer that can be used right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that what you want exists in Jinja... (at least for now)
 
If you take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues/328) the developer pretty much states that he won't do it:

> This would require patches as I'm not using pgettext myself.

Then he closed the issue.
This was created back in 2014 and something may have changed but I don't think so (based on [another issue](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues/441)).

By searching a bit around I found this project which may help: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jinja2-django-tags/0.1. There I read:

> You can also use _, gettext and pgettext directly:
>
> ```
> Simple example: {{ _('Hello World') }}
> More verbose: {{ gettext('Hello World') }}
> With context: {{ pgettext('Hello World', 'another example') }}
> ```

Good luck :)